# How can I delete a imported file in my inbox folder in my app?

Tags: ios, file, import, delete-file

How can I delete the files which where imported by the `Open in` my app function?
I noticed that my app-size grows when I open some files like PDFs in my app. It seems so, that those files will be copied to my app, how can I find and remove them?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out! The files are stored in a sub-folder of the documents-folder named "Inbox". You need to delete them there. Here is the code:

```
    NSString *fileName = @"afile.png";
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *inboxDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inbox"];
    NSString *filePath = [inboxDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSError *error;
    BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
       NSLog(@"error occured during removing the file");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A manual search for Inbox is not a very good practice in my opinion. If I have files sent to my application I remove them after I'm done processing them or if I will need them later, I move them to the cache / temp directory to prevent iCloud from backing them up.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    processUrl(url)
    removeFileAt(url)

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable itunes file sharing (http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app) and you'll probably see all files.